# Debian DNS Jessie - Subdomain to secondary server

Tags: linux, apache, dns, debian

Ok, so here i have one box

Windows Host (Debian Linux 8 VM - Oracle) -Set up. A Live Working Machine, DNS apache php...etc..

IP is `**A.A.A.A**`

second machine, fresh install, second vm, php apache all running. DNS is not.

IP is `**A.A.A.B**`

The External IPV40. ISP Router.

IP is `**X.X.X.X**`

So the Goal is simple:

On `thisdomain.com` it has a local`IP of **A.A.A.A**`
but on the Second Server it has the IP `**A.A.A.B**`

IP **A.A.A.A** Serves the domain and the website for www.thisdomain.com and thisdomain.com.`

I wish to have `ls.thisdomain.com`serve IP `**A.A.A.B**`

The`DNS`Records `are like so:

---

```
    $TTL    38400
    thisdomain.com. IN  SOA ls.thisdomain.com. webmaster.thisdomain.com. (
                        5       ; Serial
                        1d      ; Refresh
                        60m     ; Retry
                        7d      ; Expire
                        6h )        ; Negative Cache TTL
    ; ### this is the forward zone of IP 2 A.A.A.B (ls.thisdomain.com)
    thisdomain.com. IN  A   X.X.X.X
    thisdomain.com. IN  NS  ls.thisdomain.com.
    ls.thisdomain.com.  IN  A   X.X.X.X
    ls.thisdomain.com.  IN  A   A.A.A.B
    ;
    www     IN  CNAME   thisdomain.com.
    ;
```

on the main server that serves domain `IP 2 = **A.A.A.A**`:

---

```
    $TTL    38400
    thisdomain.com. IN  SOA ns1.thisdomain.com. webmaster.thisdomain.com. (
                        5       ; Serial
                        1d      ; Refresh
                        60m     ; Retry
                        7d      ; Expire
                        6h )        ; Negative Cache TTL
    ;
    thisdomain.com.      IN A   X.X.X.X
    ns1.thisdomain.com. IN  A   X.X.X.X
    ns2.thisdomain.com. IN  A   X.X.X.X
    ls.thisdomain.com.  IN  A   X.X.X.X
    thisdomain.com.     IN  NS  ls.thisdomain.com.
    ls.thisdomain.com.  IN  A   A.A.A.B
    thisdomain.com.     IN  NS  ns1.thisdomain.com.
    thisdomain.com.     IN  NS  ns2.thisdomain.com.
    ;
    www     IN  CNAME   thisdomain.com.
    ;
```

and whats this issue? well, it seems that even though i 
think there good to go, the ls.

Subdomain still only shows the first servers 
`Apache website **A.A.A.A**`
instead of the second servers 
`**A.A.A.B** Apache Website.`

What i want is it to be like this 
`ls.thisdomain.com`
hits 
`public ip X.X.X.X` 
then searches 
`NS1` on 
`IP A.A.A.A` 
then send user to webpage on server 
`LS` which is `A.A.A.B`.

How would one Achieve this to be so that it does happen?

Comment: It's unclear why you seem to have two zone files for the same domain name, can you clarify that please? Is this a domain that exists on the Internet or is it a local domain in your LAN?

Comment: The two zone files are on separate machines. and they are accessable via one public ip x.x.x.x and server 1 = a.a.a.a serves the main domain thisdomain.com and the www cname and server 2 = a.a.a.b serves the ls.thisdomain.com subdomain...however it does seem that it seems to have worked, just it seemed i was awaiting on dns propagation. i am able to access the second server on that domain. i needed to install a module for mod_rewrite and forward it through apache and that seems to have done the trick. eg. x.x.x.x => (www) a.a.a.a + (ls) a.a.a.b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are several apparent errors above. First, the whole idea of having two different zones for the same name is meaningless because it requires an unnecessary level of DNS recursion - you should serve a single consolidated DNS zone, and if you need two servers for redundancy, then make one of them master and the other one slave (a verbatim copy of the master).

Second, the second zone lists adds two additional NS records compared to the first zone, but all of those in turn point to the same IP address. This is also meaningless.

Third, the name ls.thisdomain.com is defined as a round-robin DNS entry, meaning 50% of the clients will resolve it to X.X.X.X, while another 50% will resolve it to A.A.A.B. Each of those clients will then cache that result for 38400 seconds and then repeat the query, after which point they again have a 50:50 chance of getting either result.

It's unclear from the question whether A.A.A.* is perhaps a private IP network. If the intent is to allow external users to access A.A.A.B which is in a private network, then DNS is simply not the solution. DNS is a Layer 7 protocol which doesn't care which kind of IPs its results will contain, but the external users can't route via Layer 3 to external private networks. HTTP traffic can only arrive at the public X.X.X.X IP, typically at port 80, and then the router can pass it on (NAT it) to an HTTP server. This HTTP server in turn can pass the results on to two separate virtual hosts or even two separate machines (proxying).

Comment: I honestly only understood perhaps half of that, way over my head that, but either way, it worked for what i needed it do, and there both webservers, for example 

www is one server for web/php/dns
and ls is another server for web/php/mail/dns/

Comment: @Shaun'Shorty'Cassidy thanks for being honest :) feel free to ask specific followup questions if you want something to be explained better.